# Question regarding direct products of closed subspaces of a Hilbert space

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $H$ be a Hilbert space, and let $M,N$ be closed subspaces of $H$, is it true that $M+N\subseteq \overline{ M \cup N} $? Or is there other necessary conditions for this to be true like $M,N$ must be orthogonal from each other?

Comment: This is only true if $M\subseteq N$ or $N\subseteq M$.

Answer (score 1):

No, consider the Hilbert space $\mathbb{R}^2$. Let $X$ be subspace generated by $(1,0)$ and $Y$ be the subspace generated by $(0,1)$. Now $\overline{X\cup Y}=X\cup Y$ since the finite union of closed sets is closed. But $\mathbb{R}^2=X+Y\not\subset X\cup Y$. Moreover, in this example, $X$ and $Y$ are orthogonal spaces.

Comment: I think there's something wrong with what I wrote. What if M and N are the range of the orthogonal projection operators?

Comment: I not sure what you mean by **the** orthogonal projection operators. By orthogonally projecting onto the $x$-axis and $y$-axis, you can write $X$ and $Y$ as such images, so it still fails.